# Selenium javascript webdriver how to use findElements

Tags: javascript, selenium

Want to click on third li from second ul:

```
   <ul id="select-123" style="width: 1180px; display: none;">
   <li class="" style="display:none;">
   <li class="">
   <li class="">
   <li class="">
   </ul>

   <ul id="select-123" style="width: 1180px; display: none;">
   <li class="" style="display:none;">
   <li class="">
   <li class="">
   <li class="">
   </ul>
```

Code I am trying is to select third li from second ul which does not work:

```
    driver.findElements(By.css(ul[id*='select-123'])).then(function(elems) {
    elems[2].then(function(lis) {
    driver.findElement(By.css("ul[id*='select-123'] li:nth-child(3)")).click();
    });
    });
```

Comment: you have two elements with the same id, id's should be unique

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `XPath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//ul[2]/li[3]'))
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @Andersson you also have made the mistake of having two IDs. In HTML, [IDs should be unique](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). Simply having a unique ID would have avoided this in the first place, but if you do not have control over the HTML, and someone else wrote bad HTML, the XPath solution of Andersson would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are finding elements as a list then you are using second `ul` element from the list, but when you are going to find child element of second `ul` element, you are providing `driver.findElement` which will find from whole page, so instead of this you need to find element on second `ul` element context as below :-

```
driver.findElements(By.css(ul[id*='select-123'])).then(function(elems) {
    elems[2].then(function(lis) {
      lis.findElement(By.css("ul[id*='select-123'] li:nth-child(3)")).click();
    });
});
```

Hope it works..:)